# Email is empty of other users facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I read email like this of users of facebook:

To show login link:

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '***',
  'app_secret' => '***',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  ]);
$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('https://www.****.com/fb-callback8.php', $permissions);
```

So then I receive the callback:
(to get email address, I tested this with lot of users)

```
require_once "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/vendor/autoload.php";

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => '***',
  'app_secret' => '***',
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exception\ResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exception\SDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
echo '<h3>Access Token</h3>';
var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
echo '<h3>Metadata</h3>';
var_dump($tokenMetadata);

// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId("***");
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exception\SDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $e->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;


try {
  // Returns a `Facebook\Response` object
  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email', $_SESSION['fb_access_token']);
} catch(Facebook\Exception\ResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exception\SDKException $e) {
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

$user = $response->getGraphUser();
```

Now why $user['email'] only contains my own email when using this script and not the e-mail address of other users using this code? Does facebook block or accept id's of people using this code?

Comment: Did these other users actually _grant_ the permission? Do they have an email address on file with Facebook to begin with? (Lots of users who registered using their mobile, likely won’t.)

Comment: I get empty email of users who register